# How to load the image form the srcset attribute of the <picture> in Webpack?

Tags: image, webpack, srcset

I started using the  tag in my Webpack app and noticed that the current setup is not working with the images referenced in the srcset:

```
<picture>
<source srcset="img/goal-2.jpg" media="(min-width: 675px)">
<img src="../img/goal-2-s.jpg">
</picture>
```

The goal-2-s.jpg is correctly resolved and copied over to my build folder, while the goal-2.jpg is ignored.

Currently my webpack.config.js config looks like this:

```
{
    test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif|svg)$/i,
    loader: 'file?name=img/[name].[ext]'
},...
```

I don't want to auto generate files of different sizes -- I the files I'm loading are differently cropped and I do it manually and save it in my app folder. All I want is Webpack to handle my source's srcset image in the same way as it does the img's src image.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `html-loader` only processes the `src` attribute of `<img>` tags by default (as shown in its [README](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/html-loader#usage)). But you can use the `attrs` option to make it process your desired attributes by specifying an array of `tag:attribute`. The `.html`  rule would look like this:

```
{
  test: /\.html/,
  loader: 'html-loader?attrs[]=img:src&attrs[]=source:srcset'
}
```

Or with the better webpack 2 `options` syntax:

```
{
  test: /\.html/,
  loader: 'html-loader',
  options: {
    attrs: ['img:src', 'source:srcset']
  }
}
```

Comment: Michael, thank you! This is exactly what I was looking for. Works as expected.

Comment: I tried this for img:srcset and it didn't work. Please have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51801338/webpack-html-loader-not-resolving-srcset-images.

Answer (score 0):

```
<source srcset="../img/goal-2.jpg" media="(min-width: 675px)">
```

The path was wrong

Comment: Thanks, the path is, actually, right, but changing the path is not doing anything -- it is being ignored by the Webpack no matter good or bad.